# Validate array of strings with joi, must be strings

Tags: arrays, node.js, joi

I need to validate an array to check if it's elements are strings using joi. It always sends the error of "Inavlid tag".

```
// returned array from req.body
let tags = ["Vue", "React", "Angular"]

// joi shema
const schema = {
     tags: Joi.array().items(Joi.string()),
};

const { error, value } = Joi.validate(tags, schema);

if (error) {
     return res.status(400).send({ tagError: "Invalid tag" });
}
```

Comment: BTW if you want a friendly way to return errors in an API https://github.com/hapijs/boom/blob/master/API.md I use it very often within the hapi ecosystem

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Joi was recently changed to `@hapi/joi` (literally 2 weeks ago), so make sure first and foremost that you've switched out the NPM package properly:`npm uninstall joi` and `npm i -s @hapi/joi`. Make sure to change your `require` statements for this change, also.

To define your schema in this new package, you would use:

```
const schema = Joi.array().items(Joi.string());
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is due to how you defined the schema, the right way to validate would be:

```js
// returned array from req.body
let tags = ["Vue", "React", "Angular"]

const schema = Joi.array().items(Joi.string());

const { error, value } = Joi.validate(tags, schema);
```

Comment: the current snippet is not working